# POSTing JSON object of array of JSON objects to server

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to send a JSON Object of array of JSON objects from my android app to server, but it doesen't work. I have tried it using POSTMAN and it works. The following are the codes i have tried and the json format.

Here is the JSON Format

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": 1,
            "product_name": "Smart Watch",
            "product_price": 99.99
        },

        {
            "product_id": 2,
            "product_name": "Smart TV",
            "product_price": 999.99
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is POJO Class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Product {

    @SerializedName("product_id")
        public int productId;
        @SerializedName("product_name")
        public String productName;
        @SerializedName("product_price")
        public double productPrice;



    public Product(Integer productId, String productName, Float productPrice) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;

    }

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId){
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getproductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setproductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getproductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setproductPrice(String productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }


}
```

Here is my ServiceGenerator Class

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl)
    {
        Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        return builder.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Added another class Customers

```
public class Customers {
    @SerializedName("customers")
    public List<Customer> customers;

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public void setCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }
}
```

Here is my Interface Class

```
public interface IRetrofit {
    @Headers({

            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("addproduct")
    Call<Products> postRawJSON(@Body Products products);


}
```

and My MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onPostClicked(View view){

        // Using the Retrofit
        IRetrofit jsonPostService = ServiceGenerator.createService(IRetrofit.class, "http://192.168.122.1/productmanager/products/");


        Product product = new Products(null, "Samsung Galaxy A5", 234.54);
        Call<Product> call = jsonPostService.postRawJSON(product);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
                try{
                    Log.e("response-success", response.body().toString());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("response-failure", call.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have called the `onPostClicked()` method from the layout `android:OnClicked` property.

I have also edited the `AnroidManifest` File and added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and am connected to the same network.

Using POSTMAN i tried sending this and it works(adds it to the db)

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "product_name": "Galaxy A2",
            "product_price": 599.99
        }


    ]
}
```

and when i send a GET Request it also shows me it has added the new record

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "product_id": 1,
            "product_name": "Smart Watch",
            "product_price": 99.99
        },

        {
            "product_id": 2,
            "product_name": "Smart TV",
            "product_price": 999.99
        },
 {
                "product_id": 3,
                "product_name": "Galaxy A2",
                "product_price": 599.99
            }

    ]
}
```

Here is my Log

```
I/TAG: --> POST http://192.168.122.1/productmanager/products/ http/1.1
       Content-Type: application/json
       Content-Length: 249
       Accept: application/json
I/TAG: {"product_id":"","product_name":"Samsung Galaxy A5","product_price":234.5}
       --> END POST (249-byte body)
I/TAG: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.122.1/productmanager/products/addcproduct (266ms)
       Date: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 12:29:59 GMT
       Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/5.6.37
       X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.37
       Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
       Connection: Keep-Alive
       Transfer-Encoding: chunked
       Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
I/TAG: <pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');"><b>Notice</b> (8)</a>: Undefined index: products [<b>APP/Controller\productsController.php</b>, line <b>77</b>]<div id="cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-trace" class="cake-stack-trace" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-code').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-code').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Code</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-context').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-context').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Context</a><pre id="cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-code" class="cake-code-dump" style="display: none;"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$product&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$productTable</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">newEntity</span><span style="color: #007700">();</span></span></code>
       <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$products&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">request</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">data</span><span style="color: #007700">[</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'products'</span><span style="color: #007700">];</span></span></code></span>
       <code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">if&nbsp;(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">request</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">is</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'post'</span><span style="color: #007700">))&nbsp;{</span></span></code></pre><pre id="cakeErr5bae1ec79e019-context" class="cake-context" style="display: none;">$res = []
       $productTable = object(App\Model\Table\ProductsTable) {

        &#039;registryAlias&#039; =&gt; &#039;products&#039;,
        &#039;table&#039; =&gt; &#039;products&#039;,
        &#039;alias&#039; =&gt; &#039;products&#039;,
        &#039;entityClass&#039; =&gt; &#039;App\Model\Entity\product&#039;,
        &#039;associations&#039; =&gt; [],
        &#039;behaviors&#039; =&gt; [],
        &#039;defaultConnection&#039; =&gt; &#039;default&#039;,
        &#039;connectionName&#039; =&gt; &#039;default&#039;

       }
       $product = object(App\Model\Entity\product) {

        &#039;[new]&#039; =&gt; true,
        &#039;[accessible]&#039; =&gt; [
            &#039;product_id&#039; =&gt; true,
            &#039;product_name&#039; =&gt; true,
            &#039;product_price&#039; =&gt; true,

        ],
        &#039;[dirty]&#039; =&gt; [],
        &#039;[original]&#039; =&gt; [],
        &#039;[virtual]&#039; =&gt; [],
        &#039;[errors]&#039; =&gt; [],
        &#039;[invalid]&#039; =&gt; [],
        &#039;[repository]&#039; =&gt; &#039;products&#039;

       }</pre><pre class="stack-trace">App\Controller\productsController::addproduct() - APP/Controller\ProductsController.php, line 77
       Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 440
       Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 119
       Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 93
       Cak
       <-- END HTTP (22852-byte body)
E/response-failure: retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@4958691
```

Please help. Thank You in advance

Comment: http://192.168.122.1 is local network IP address. It will work if it is connected to same notwork.

Comment: Yes, i am connected to the same network, but it still doesn't work

Comment: open http://192.168.122.1/productmanager/products/addproduct in your test device browser and tell me the result

Comment: @VinayakB it shows a bunch of errors, but i tried it using postman on my host device, and it works(adds the product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `List` of `Product` as `@Body`. Which means your Request model is an Object which contains a List of `Product` objects

Try creating the POJO classes like this

```
        public class Product {
            @SerializedName("product_id")
            public int productId;
            @SerializedName("product_name")
            public String productName;
            @SerializedName("product_price")
            public double productPrice;
        }

        public class ProductRequest {
            @SerializedName("products")
            public List<Product> products;
        }
```

*Note: Add setters and getters if you are making fields private*

Then in your retrofit interface

```
     Call<JsonObject> postRawJSON(@Body ProductRequest products);
```

Also, Instead of `JsonObject` use the POJO class for your response JSON structure

**Update:** 
**Do the following steps**

1) Create the `ProductRequest` model like this

```
    ProductRequest productRequest = new ProductRequest();
    ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    Product product = new Product(1, "Samsung Galaxy A5", 234.54);
    productList.add(product);
    productRequest.products = productList;
```

2) Create a POJO class for the response JSON of this API. For example create a `ProductResponse` class.  Since I don't know your response structure, I assume it would be something like

```
{
  "code" : 200 , 
  "status" : "Success"
}
```

So for the above Response , the POJO class you have to create as follows

```
 public class ProductResponse {
    @SerializedName("code")
    public int code;
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
}
```

3) Create your `IRetrofit` interface like this

```
    public interface IRetrofit {
    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("addproduct")
    Call<ProductResponse> addProducts(@Body ProductRequest productRequest);
```

4) Now in your `Activity` following is the full code to create the `Request` (as shown Step 1) and call the API

```
    ProductRequest productRequest = new ProductRequest();
    ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    Product product = new Product(1, "Samsung Galaxy A5", 234.54);
    productList.add(product);
    productRequest.products = productList;

    Call<ProductResponse> productResponseCall = jsonPostService.addProducts(productRequest);
    productResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<ProductResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ProductResponse> call, Response<ProductResponse> response) {
            ProductResponse productResponse = response.body(); // this  your result

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ProductResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("response-failure", call.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am trying to send one product at a time actually.

Comment: But the JSON what you have posted in the question is the structure expected by your server right?

Comment: Not necessarily as i have said i tried it using postman, i just sent a product and it worked

Comment: Please post your error log. What error are you getting

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't work. It doesn't add the new record

Comment: You said you are sending one object via postman and in your updated question still you are sending a list only??

Comment: Yes, but that works. I don't know what else to do. How can I change that in my JAVA class

Comment: Both of your JSON structures are the same. There's no difference in the POJO structure in both these cases. In the first JSON you are sending a list of 1 object, second JSON sends a list of 3 objects. Both the cases you are sending list only. So the answer which I have posted should work and thats how you need to create the POJO structure.

Comment: I did as u have said and posted the log.

Comment: I think still you are not sending in the proper format. You are sending a single object, not a List as the server expects. `{"product_id":"","product_name":"Samsung Galaxy A5","product_price":234.5}`  this is your input as per log. It should have been like 
`{    "products":  [{"product_id":"","product_name":"Samsung Galaxy A5","product_price":234.5} ]    }`

Comment: make sure that you have made the classes properly as shown in the answer. And what is the response JSON of this API?

Comment: Am sorry but how do i exactly do that??

Comment: Create those classes which I  have mentioned in the answer and use it as the body as I have shown. I have edited the answer and renamed the class for better understanding

Comment: I created those classes, i created a new class for ProductRequest.

Comment: What is your server response JSON structure for this API? Please post it.

Comment: I am sorry but after i created those classes, what do i have to change in my MainActivity

Comment: I have updated the answer with all the steps. Please try it once

Comment: Thank You Thank You. @Srt. It worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your server requires you to send a list of Products, in your Android app you are sending 1 product (1 Java model). What you should do is send a list of models.

You could have avoided this problem if you gave your classes better names

```
Products products = new Products(null, "Samsung Galaxy A5", 234.54);
```

is bad because you are not creating product**s** but **a** product.

Comment: I am actually trying to send one product at a time

Comment: Does your API accept an endpoint where only one product can be send?

Comment: If it does not, then you can create an ArrayList of 1 Product and send that object instead.

Comment: I have edited my post. I tried using postman and just sent one and it worked

Comment: You are still sending a **list** of 1 product. Change your Java code to what is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550479/3999808
IF THIS DOES NOT WORK, POST YOUR LOG

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your JSON sample, server accepts **JSONObject** which contains **JSONArray** of product**s**

You tested it using Postman with same parameters as your server accepts. But, in your application you're preparing an object of `Product` class and passing it to API request. So, the final payload will be like below,

```
{
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_name": "Smart Watch",
    "product_price": 99.99
}
```

Just a JSONObject of products instead of products JSONArray.

Follow what [@Srt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3970618/srt) suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52550629/5180017). That's correct way of sending data to your API (as per the requirement)

And also I came across your comments posted under other answers here. In one of them you said

> **There is no error, it just doesn't work.** It doesn't add the new record – S.Jay

To check what's happening while Retrofit executing network requests, you need to add [OkHttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) which logs every single request (including errors) being executed through Retrofit library.

Add this dependency to your `build.gradle` (app level) and sync the project

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
```

After syncing the project add below code into `ServiceGenerator` class

```
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import android.util.Log;

public class ServiceGenerator {

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String baseUrl) {

    // add logging interceptor to OkHttpClient
     httpClient.addInterceptor(getInterceptor());

    Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

      return builder.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static HttpLoggingInterceptor getInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
           @Override
           public void log(String message) {
               Log.i("TAG", message);
           }
        });
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return interceptor;
    }
}
```

Just add HttpLoggingInterceptor to OkHttpClient like I mentioned in above code. (or copy and paste the code)

Now, that should log every single request.

Comment: I have accepted and edited my code according to @Srt, and i have posted my log error

Comment: Still you're sending the same JSON body `{"product_id":"","product_name":"Samsung Galaxy A5","product_price":234.5}` (look into Retrofit logging interceptor's log message) which causing the following error at server side `Undefined index: products [APP/Controller\productsController.php, line 77]` Not sure why you're not understanding [or following] the @Srt s answer.